# pySerial: port only works the first I use it after I power it on

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I have trouble reading an arbitrary port with pySerial. I can only read the port when the port hasn't been used by any program after it's turned on. Otherwise, I can open the port but ser.inWaiting() returns 0, telling me there is no data in the port buffer.  Actually, I can see data in a port monitor, so why does pySerial gets no data? I am using os x 10.9.5., python 2.7.8 and pySerial 2.7

Here is the code:

```
def usb():
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem422651', 115200)
    try:
        while True:
            print ser.read(1000)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        ser.close()
         exit


if __name__ == "__main__":
    testUSB()
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand how serial works.

If you already opened some terminal and read the data, then it's **the input buffer of the serial port is now empty.**

```
while True:
   print ser.read(1000)
```

It's not a good practice, you can try the following using [inWating](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.inWaiting):

```
if ser.inWaiting:
   ser.read(len(ser.inWaiting()))
```

**You cannot open the port from 2 different apps or software.**

**A good code will look like:**

```
import serial


def my_usb():
    s_handle = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem422651', 115200)

# or any other end condition
while True:
    try:
        if s_handle.inWaiting():
            print s_handle.read(s_handle.inWaiting())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "exiting...."
    finally:
        s_handle.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_usb()
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I found out, that i can't use the port a second time when I didn't read all bytes from buffer the first time i used the port.
You're right with the inWaiting!

Comment: NP, Just remember serial ports doesn't have memory it's like a queue if you pop out the data to a software or stdout (screen) the ports queue will be empty, Also if the answer solved the problem you can accept it as an answer.